# Bind Data multiple checkbox reactive form angular 4

Tags: angular

In Component:

```
 constructor(private prodService: productService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.prodService.profile()
        .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.interested = result.category; //Get all product
          this.checkReuslt = result.resultSet.interest_categroy; /// user select product

        }
      )

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formProfile = this.fb.group({
      interested: this.fb.array([]),
    });
  }
```

In View:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of interested">
    <input type="checkbox" value="data.id" (change)="onChange(data.id, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.cat_name}}<br>
</div>
```

How to bind data to the checkbox in reactive form

```html
  In Component: 
 constructor(private prodService: productService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.prodService.profile()
        .subscribe(
        result => {
          this.interested = result.category; //Get all product
          this.checkReuslt = result.resultSet.interest_categroy; /// user select product
        
        }
      )

      ngOnInit() {
        this.formProfile = this.fb.group({
          interested: this.fb.array([]),
        });
      }
   
In View:
         <div *ngFor="let data of interested">
                <input type="checkbox" value="data.id" (change)="onChange(data.id, $event.target.checked)"> {{data.cat_name}}<br>
              </div>
    
    How to bind data to the checkbox in reactive form
```

Answer (score 0):

I added both `FormArray` and `FormGroup` to the form as `FormGroup` might be easier to work with later.

In TS:

```
constructor(private prodService: productService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.formProfile = this.fb.group({
    interested: this.fb.array([]),
    interestedGroup: this.fb.group({}),
  });

  this.prodService.profile().subscribe(result => {
    this.interested = result.category; //Get all product
    this.checkResult = result.resultSet.interest_category;

    const interestArr: FormArray = this.formProfile.get('interested') as FormArray;
    const interestGr: FormGroup = this.formProfile.get('interestedGroup') as FormGroup;

    this.interested.forEach(n => {
      const initVal = this.checkResult.indexOf(n.id) > -1;
      interestArr.push(this.fb.control(initVal));
      interestGr.addControl(n.cat_name, this.fb.control(initVal));
    });
  });
}
```

And template:

```
<form [formGroup]="formProfile">
  <ng-container formGroupName="interested">
    <div *ngFor="let interest of interested; let i = index;">
      <input [formControlName]="i" type="checkbox">{{interest.cat_name}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>

  <hr>

  <ng-container formGroupName="interestedGroup">
    <div *ngFor="let interest of interested">
      <input [formControlName]="interest.cat_name" type="checkbox">{{interest.cat_name}}
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</form>

<pre>{{formProfile.value | json}}</pre>
```

Comment: thank you so much further i have added some code:
 this.interested.forEach(n => {
            if(this.checkReuslt.indexOf(n.id)!=-1){
              interestGr.addControl(n.id, this.fb.control(true));
            }else{
              interestGr.addControl(n.id, this.fb.control(false));
            }
                    
          });

Comment: I modified the answer to have initial value. HTH and it is all working for you.

Comment: @user2686713 if that all works and you have no further queries would you care to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)?